# How to hide a menu item of a view for an administrator?

Tags: views, 8, users

I have created a view with Views and restricted the access by Role. I also created a menu with the view, and I didn't select the Administrator role to be included (so Administrator role does not have access to that view). But the view's menu item is still showing to the Administrator.

How can I hide that menu item for Administrators?

**Notes**:

- This also happens for a user with a `uid` which is NOT `user/1`.
- The menu item is shown, but the administrator can't actually access the actual views results.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thank you, i'll try to creat an admin, maybe who will not have the uid=1 to test this and l'ill tell you if your comment is the answer.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes, it was the uid=1 but when i tried to add the admin role to another user it still shows the menu entry, so it's not the fact that it is uid=1

Comment: ok, next question: the menu item still shows, but what happens if such user tries to actually clicks on that menu item? Does such user get access to the actual views results?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes the menu item shows but the administrator can't acess the actual views results

Comment: Please review my edit of your question, trying to make it more accurate/clear what your actual question is (mostly by integrating your comments). Feel free to further refine/adapt (or rollback if you don't like my edit at all). Good luck!